# Integrable function and measure space

Tags: measure-theory

I have two similar problem in measure space.

1. let $f$ be an integrable function on a measure space $X,M,\mu$ such that
   $$\int_{E} f \, d\mu = 0$$for all sets $E \in M$.
2. let $f$ be an integrable function on a measure space $R,L,\lambda$ (that is lebesgue space and measure) such that
   $$\int_{a}^b f \, d\lambda = 0$$
   for all $-\infty<a<b<\infty$.

I wanna prove that $f=0$ $a.e.$ both case

I got an intution that I can using that fact:
$$\lambda\left\{x\mid f(x)\geq \frac 1n\right\}\leq n\int f \, d\lambda=0,$$ 
But, I can't apply that precisely. Could you give some hints?

Comment: Why can't you apply this inequality?

Comment: Hint: apply your intuition to $f^{+}$ and $f^{-}$.

Comment: Okay I'll try it now. I'm not good at kind of proofs.

Comment: I can only give result for $\lambda(f^+(x)>0)=\lambda(f^-(x)>0)$, not $\lambda(f(x)!=0)=0$ using that inequality in first problem. How can I go more steps?

Comment: I wrote [an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141406/how-to-show-that-f-0-a-e-on-0-1-times-0-1/141718#141718) addressing the same problem in two dimensions. Warning: it's more than a hint.

Comment: Thank you for your helps all. At this time I likely understood almost everywhere concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $f \geq 0$. Then, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, consider $A_n = \{ x \in X \mid f(x)>1/n\}$. Then $$\frac{1}{n} \mu (A_n) \leq \int_{A_n} f \, d\mu  \leq \int_X f \, d\mu =0.$$ Hence $\mu(A_n)=0$ for every $n$, and $f(x) \leq 1/n$ for almost every $x \in X$. We conclude that $f=0$ a.e.

In the general case, write $f=f^{+}-f^{-}$. By assumption, $\int_E f^{+}\, d\mu=0$ for $E=\{x \in X \mid f(x) \geq 0\}$. Therefore $f^{+}=0$ a.e. You can conclude in a similar way that $f^{-}=0$ a.e.

Part 2 is less standard, since you have to remember that Lebesgue's measure is built from intervals.

Answer (score 0):

First $f = Max(0; f)-Max(0;-f)$.
Let focus on $Max(0; f)$ that means when the function is positive. We note it $f$ by commodity. Concerning $Max(0;-f)$ the prove will be very similar.

1-We know that: $\{x \in X: f(x)>0\}=\bigcup_n \{x \in X: f(x)\geq \frac 1n\}$

2-Now let's note the following inequality:
$0=\int_{x \in X}^{}f(x) d \mu (x) = \int_{x \in X: f(x)>0}^{}f(x) d \mu (x) + \int_{x \in X : f(x)=0}^{}f(x) d \mu (x) \geq \int_{x \in X: f(x)>0}^{}f(x) d \mu (x) > \int_{x \in X :  f(x) \geq \frac{1}{n}}f(x) d \mu (x) \geq \frac{1}{n} \mu(\left \{ x \in X: f(x) \geq \frac{1}{n} \right \}) \geq 0 \Rightarrow \mu(\left \{ x \in X: f(x) \geq \frac{1}{n} \right \})=0$
*Rem:* by definition $\mu(.) \geq 0 $
We have now proved that $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\mu(\left \{ x \in X: f(x) \geq \frac{1}{n} \right \})=0$

3-Apply $\mu(.)$ on the both side of the equality in "1-" we get: $\mu (\{x \in X: f(x)>0\})=\mu (\bigcup_n \{x \in X: f(x)\geq \frac 1n\})$.
But $0 \leq \mu (\bigcup_n \{x \in X: f(x)\geq \frac 1n\}) \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{} \mu(\left \{ x \in X: f(x) \geq \frac{1}{n} \right \})=0 $

Conclusion, by definition $f(x)=0$ a.e.
Q.E.D.