# Show that $\int f=0$ implies $f=0$ a.e, given that $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to show that $\int f=0$ implies $f=0$ a.e, given that $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function.

But I search my head from what I have learn I have no any clue of solving the problem. That is why I brought it to this room with the hope that somebody will give me a hint.

Thanks

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142668/integrable-function-and-measure-space

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint: $\{x: f(x)>0\}=\bigcup_n \{x: f(x)\geq \frac 1n\}$. So it suffices to show that $\{x: f(x)\geq\frac 1n\}$ has measure $0$.

Comment: Is the measure of the set $\{x:f(x) \ge \frac {1}{n}\}$ zero?

Comment: The integral of $f$ over that set is $\ge 1/n$ times the measure of that set.  So that integral is positive and hence $\int f$ is positive, if the measure of that set is positive.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: let $A_n:=\{f(x)\geq 2^{-n}\}$. Write $0\geq \int_{A_n}f(x)d\mu\geq 2^{-n}\mu(A_n)$. What about $\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_n\right)$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\int_E f = 0$ for a (Lebesgue) measurable set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$. Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary, and consider $f^{-1}([\frac{1}{k}, \infty])$. Using Chebyshev's inequality, we see that $$m(f^{-1}([1/k, \infty])) \leq k \int_E f = 0.$$ Since $k$ was arbitrary and $[\frac{1}{k} , \infty] \subseteq [\frac{1}{k+1}, \infty]$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, by continuity of measure (and since limits respect order) we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k \to \infty} m(f^{-1}([1/k, \infty])) &= m\left (\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} f^{-1}([1/k, \infty]) \right)  = m\left (f^{-1}((0, \infty]) \right) \\
&\leq \lim_{k \to \infty} \left(k \int_E f \right) = \lim_{k \to \infty} (k\cdot 0) = 0
\end{align*}

Therefore, $f^{-1}((0, \infty])$ has measure zero. By non-negativity, $f= 0 $ a.e. in $E$.