# Why does $f\in \mathcal{L}_+^0$ and $\int fd\mu=0\implies f=0$ almost everywhere?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

If $f\in \mathcal{L}_+^0$ and $\int fd\mu=0$, where $\mathcal{L}_+^0$ is the set of all measurable $[0,\infty]$-valued functions, 
Does that Implies $f=0$ almost everywhere? If so why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $\int f=0$ implies $f=0$ a.e, given that $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147887/show-that-int-f-0-implies-f-0-a-e-given-that-f-is-a-nonnegative-measurab)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
\begin{align}
\int_{|f|\geq 1/n} f\ d\mu \geq \frac{1}{n}\mu\{x \mid |f|\geq n^{-1}\}
\end{align}

Comment: $0=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{|f|\geq n^{-1}} fd\mu \geq \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\mu\left\{x| |f|\geq n^{-1}\right\}$?

Comment: Nope. You should consider $\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}\{x \mid |f|\geq n^{-1}\}$.

Comment: $\cap_n \{x\mid |f| \geq n^{-1}\}\subseteq \frac{1}{n}\{x\mid |f|\geq n^{-1}\} \implies \mu(\cup_n\{x\mid |f|\geq n^{-1}\})\leq \mu(\frac{1}{n}\{x\mid |f|\geq n^{-1}\}) \leq \int_{|f|\geq 1/n} f\ d\mu=0?$

Comment: If the last one is not true I am out of ideas..