Question Regarding $\mathbb{E}X=0$ implies that $X=0$ a.s.
For a non-negative simple random variable X. $\mathbb{E}X=0$ implies that $X=0 \:a.s.$
Books give a proof that
$let \: X=\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}x_{k}\mathbb{1}_{A_{k}} where\: x_{k}\geq0
, A_{1}=\{X=0\}
, then \:\mathbb{E}X=\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}x_{k}\mathbb{P}(A_{k})=0
$ implies that $\mathbb{P}(A_{k})=0 \:\forall x_{k}>0,k\geq2$ therefore $\mathbb{P}(X=0)=1$
I don't understand the last step. My thoght is that
$$\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{1\leq k\leq n}A_{k})=P(A_{1})=1\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(X=0)=1$$
But if for some i, $x_{i}=0$ so that $\mathbb{P}(A_{i})\neq 0$ then the above equation doesn't satisfied.

What are $A_k$ and $x_k$?  I think that $x_k$ are supposed to be the nonzero values taken by $X$, and $A_k$ is the event $X = x_k$.  Since $x_k = 0$ is not allowed, your objection does not apply.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147888

I'm assuming that $A_k=\{X=x_k\}$ and $A_1=\{X=0\}$, i.e. $x_1=0$?
I think your idea for the proof is correct. What you brought up is not a contradiction, since the formula $\sum_{k=1}^nP(A_k)=1$
can only be applied if the sample space can be written as the disjoint union $\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k$. If there is $i\neq 1$ such that $x_i=0$, then $A_1=A_i$ and  $\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k$ is not a disjoint union (unless the sets $A_1$ and $A_i$ are both empty). So, we should be picking $\{x_i\}$ such that $x_i\neq x_j$ when $i\neq j$.

Markov inequality says for $X\geq 0$ $$\Pr(X\geq \epsilon)=E (1_{X\geq \epsilon})\leq E(\frac{X}{\epsilon})=\frac{1}{\epsilon}E(X).$$ If $E(X)=0$ we have  $\Pr(X\geq \epsilon)=0.$ If $A_n=\{X\geq 1/n\}$ then $\{X>0\}=\cup_nA_n.$ Therefore $\Pr(X>0)=0=1-\Pr(X=0).$

This is very clear. Thank you!

The book starts the proof by considering a nonnegative simple function $X = \sum_{i=1}^n a_k1_{A_k}$. Simple functions attain only a finite number of values, say $\{b_1, \ldots, b_m\}$, so that we can write $X = \sum_{i=1}^m = b_i 1_{\{X = b_i\}}$. Without loss of generality, we assume that $b_1 = 0$ (if not, we can add it to the above representation of the simple function). Recall that the expectation of a simple function is independent of the representation of the simple function. Now, $b_i > 0$ for $i=2, \ldots, m$, so
\begin{align*}
0 =EX = \sum_{i=1}^m b_iP(X = b_i),
\end{align*}
which implies that for $i > 2$, $P(X = b_i) = 0$, as $b_i > 0$. (Note that $b_1 = 0$, so the sum doesn't immediately tell us anything about $P(X = 0)$). The events $\{X = b_1\}, \ldots, \{X=b_m\}$ are pairwise disjoint, and, span the entire underlying sample space $\Omega$, by the assumption of $X$ only taking the values $\{b_1, \ldots, b_m\}$. We therefore have that
\begin{align*}
1 = P(\Omega) = P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^m\{X = b_i\}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^m P(X = b_i) &\iff \\
P(X = 0) = 1-\sum_{i=2}^mP(X=b_i) = 1.
\end{align*}
So indeed, $X = 0$ $P$-a.s, which is what we wanted to show.
Addendum:
If we would like to extend this to general nonnegative measurable $X$, take any simple nonnegative sequence $S_n \uparrow X$. In particular, as $EX = 0$, $ES_n = 0$, so $P(S_n = 0) = 1$. Because $S_n \uparrow X$, we have that $\{S_n = 0\} \downarrow \{X = 0\}$, so
\begin{align*}
P(X=0) = P\left(\bigcap \{S_n = 0\}_{n=1}^\infty\right) = 1,
\end{align*}
because a countable intersection of sets of probability $1$ has probability $1$.

Hi, I get the idea of the proof but I'm still confused about following two details: How do we ensure that the events {=1},…,{=} are pairwise disjoint, and, span the entire underlying sample space Ω. What if there are some $1\leq i,j \leq m : s.t. b_i=b_j$, does it hold that ${X=b_i}\bigcap{X=b_j}=\emptyset$. Is this hold by using the definition of mapping? Furthermore, why  ↑ implies that {=0}↓{=0}, can you elaborate more on this?

The fact that they are pairwise disjoint indeed follows from the fact that $X$ is a function. The fact that they span the whole sample space follows from the fact that every $\omega$ is mapped onto some $b_i$. The last question, this is something you may think about yourself; what does it mean for a non negative sequence $S_n$ to increase to a non negative $X$?

The three hypothesis

$X=\sum_{1\le k\le n}x_k\Bbb 1_{A_k}$
$x_k\ge0\;(\forall k)$
$\sum_{1\le k\le n}x_k\Bbb P(A_k)=0$

are sufficient. No need to assume that $A_1=\{X=0\}$ and $(\forall k>1)\;x_k\ne0$, or that the $A_k$s are pairwise disjoint. Simply use that $\mathbb P(\cup_{x_k>0}A_k)=0$, and that $\{X=0\}$ is the complementary event.
Note that this theorem is much more general than the special case (random variable with finite range) considered in your book.
